# How to query subview of UIView with tag?

Tags: iphone, uiview, subview

i insert 2 UIImageView with tag 1 and 100 to UIView,

how to access to UIView and check how many subview on it or select tag 1 to be the top of view ?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

"check how many subview on it"

```
[myView.subviews count];
```

"or select tag 1 to be the top of view"

```
[myView bringSubviewToFront:[myView viewWithTag:1]];
```